# How to create a webpage that captures the user's camera in phone and camputers?

Tags: html, camera, cross-browser, getusermedia

I am trying to build a web-page that capture the user's media stream ( take a picture of ID card and such documents..) on phone and on computers, then allow the user to crop the image in order to remove unwanted parts, then send the picture of the document to an ocr server to be treated.

I know this is a lot of work. 
 I have found many page that work on computers but not om my phone ( android) I couldn't figure the crop part yet  and  I don't know how to send it to the server of the website I would like to use to OCR it.

If you have anything that will help I am eternally grateful

Comment: In the getUserMedia world, don't go for eternal gratitude :-) Any advice you get will probably be valid for *much* less time than that. It's changing fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getUserMedia()` works inconsistently on different browsers and devices, as you have discovered. (Compatibility is a notorious pain in the neck in this area.) You can use the sample at this URL to test the basic snapshot functionality. https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/canvas/

That example code places its result in an ordinary 2d canvas (canvases actually work on multiple browsers.)

I won't attempt to describe the cropping operation here, other than to say it works with canvas elements, and places its result in another canvas. You can find [plenty](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/281/top-7-best-image-cropping-javascript-and-jquery-plugins) of [implementations](http://www.croppic.net/) with a simple web search.

In Javascript, once you have the croppedCanvas with the desired image, you use [toBlob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) like this:

```
  var quality = 0.8
  croppedCanvas.toBlob(
     function callback (blob) {
       /* POST the blob here */
     }, 
     'image/jpg',
     quality);
```

In the callback you get a [Blob object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) containing the encoded (jpegged) image. You can then, from within the callback, POST it to your server with an [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#Sending_binary_data) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) operation.

I fear your question covers many topics, so I haven't written sample code for everything. But this should get you started. (I had to crawl through all this recently myself, and it is a struggle to figure it all out.)

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer, this should get me started I will check and try to figure how can I put this together.  Btw, not wrong with the "eternal" remark  I agree :-)